# PythonのKeyboardモジュールでキーが押されているか確認する方法について

Tags: python

Pythonの[Keyboardモジュール](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/)を使って以下のコードを作成してみました。
キーボードのホットキーを登録し、キーが押されたらexecuteHotKey関数が実行されます。

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import keyboard 

class threadingGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame=1
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None

    def executeHotKey(self):
        print("key press")

    #時間をカウント
    def time_count(self):
        while not self.stop_flag:
            #keyboard.read_hotkey()
            if keyboard.is_pressed('a') == True:
                print("test")
            print(self.frame)
            self.frame=self.frame+1
            time.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            #キーボード入力を待ち受ける
            keyboard.add_hotkey('a', self.executeHotKey)
            keyboard.add_hotkey('b', self.executeHotKey)
            keyboard.add_hotkey('c', self.executeHotKey) 
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.time_count)
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()


    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

        self.stop_flag=True
        self.thread.join()

t = threadingGUI()
t.GUI_start()
```

上記のコードで、キーボードのaキーを押すと問題なくexecuteHotKey関数が実行され
コンソールに"key press"と表示されます。

しかし、私は毎フレームごとに押されているキーの状態も知りたいため、以下のような記述をしているのですが、これが反応してくれません。

```
    if keyboard.is_pressed('a') == True:
        print("test")
```

キーが押されているかどうかを取得するにはどうしたら良いのでしょうか？

Comment: [keyboard.stash_state()](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboardstash_state)というのが有るようですが、説明を見ると上手く動くか不明ですね。1回呼んだら状態がリセットされて2回目以降は意味の無いデータになるかも。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyPress event を記録しておくのはどうでしょうか。以下のコードでは `threadingGUI.keypressed` に KeyPress event を追加していて、`threading.lock(threading.Lock() instance)` で排他制御を行っています。

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time
import keyboard

class threadingGUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame=1
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.keypressed = []
        self.stop_flag=False
        self.thread=None

    def executeHotKey(self, c):
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.keypressed.append(c)
        self.lock.release()
        print("key press")

    #時間をカウント
    def time_count(self):
        while not self.stop_flag:
            self.lock.acquire()
            if 'a' in self.keypressed:
                print("test")
            self.keypressed = []
            self.lock.release()
            print(self.frame)
            self.frame=self.frame+1
            time.sleep(1)

    def start(self):
        if not self.thread:
            #キーボード入力を待ち受ける
            [keyboard.add_hotkey(c, self.executeHotKey, args=(c))
             for c in ('a', 'b', 'c')]
            self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.time_count)
            self.stop_flag=False
            self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        if self.thread:
            self.stop_flag=True
            self.thread.join()
            self.thread=None

    def GUI_start(self):
        root=tk.Tk()
        Button001=tk.Button(root,text="Start",command=self.start)
        Button001.pack()
        Button002=tk.Button(root,text="Stop",command=self.stop)
        Button002.pack()
        root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    t = threadingGUI()
    t.GUI_start()
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。無事動きました！ただ、私が排他制御についてあまり理解できていないのでより詳しく質問をさせて頂きたいです。このコードで、排他制御に関する処理を省いても同様の動きをするように見えるので、排他制御が何故必要なのか知りたいです。また、executeHotKey関数の中と、time_count関数の中で両方でlock.acquire()とlock.release()をする必要があるのは何故なのでしょうか？

Comment: time_count() と executeHotKey() は別々のスレッドで実行されていますので、self.keypressed 変数に同時にアクセス(read or update)する可能性があるためです。例えば、time_count() での `if 'a' in self.keypressed:` の直後のタイミングで `a` が入力された場合、self.keypressed 変数がリセットされてしまい、キー入力がされなかったという状態になる事も考えられるわけです。